# Why bound currents cannot be detected in experiment?

Tags: electromagnetism

In today's group meeting about anomalous Nernst effect, I learned that bound currents cannot be detected in experiment. Why?

Comment: You may want to read this treatment of them, I found it quite informative on this exact issue: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1e8d/bdc6c57bbfd82acc53883b1475ab270c36a2.pdf

Comment: So you mean bound currents are measurable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the answer. It's in the article *Cooper, N. R., B. I. Halperin, and I. M. Ruzin, 1997, Phys. Rev.B 55, 2344.*  Bound currents do not make any contribution to the net current flows that are measured by conventional transport experiments. Specifically, consider any closed curve C that encircles the sample but is exterior to it, and let S be a surface spanning this contour. The total magnetization currents crossing the surface must be zero, by Stokes’s theorem, and the total currents IS crossing the surface are obtained by considering the transport currents alone.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

While finding the vector potential due to piece of magnetized material with magnetization  **M** ,it is turn out that it is same as potential produced by a volume current and a surface current called bound current. Physical interpretation for them that in uniform magnetized material there tiny current loops which produces dipole moment.[image]

The net effect of these loop is a surface current.[image]

It is clear that it's just an analogy too understand the net effect of those tiny loop.If you try to measure the surface bound current ,you will unable as there only tiny current loops in reality.

Comment: But the net effects of these tiny loops are volume current and surface current. Is it because measurement will disturb these tiny loops so that the volume current and surface current are changed so that we cannot measure them?

Comment: What I mean is that these tiny current loop is equivalent to a system with a surface current and volume current it does mean if you measure a current you get that current but the magnetic field will same in both the case ie.  In case of magnetized substance and a object with surface and volume current.